# Integrability of indicator of $f(x) \geq 0$ for a continuous function f.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x)$ be some continuous function of $x$, and
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{when }f(x) \geq 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

- Is $g(x)$ Lebesgue integrable over any finite interval $[a, b]$?
- Also, is it Riemann integrable over $[a, b]$?

If not, is there a natural set of conditions on the class of continuous functions for which it is integrable?

Comment: The set $\{x\mid f(x)>0\}$ is open by continuity, so thus it is measurable, which implies $g$ is measurable. However, it isn't necessarily integrable.

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: You have to define the domain you are integrating over for this to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: Domain is any finite interval. I also made an edit to the question to clarify this.

Comment: @Alan Is the following argument correct?
 $g(x)$ can have at most countably many points of discontinuities since $f(x)$ is continuous. So $g(x)$ is continuous almost everywhere, which implies that it is integrable.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: The title says $\{f>0\}$ and the actual question says $\{f\ge 0\}.$ Which is it?

Comment: The answer to your question to @Alan is no. The set of discontinuities of $g$ can have positive measure.

Comment: @zwh I was really confused, trying to figure out what my question was there.  IT was actually from the OP who just tagged me :).

Comment: (1) You seem to be asking at least three different questions here (about Lebesgue integrability, Riemann integrability, and the integrability of continuous functions).  Please try to ask only one question at a time. (2) Your question is lacking context.  Please edit your question to explain what you know, what definitions might be helpful (e.g. the definitions of Riemann and Lebesgue integrability), and any thoughts you might have on the problem.

Comment: I have refunded your bounty, so that you can make improvements to your question(s) without encouraging answers to respond to a half-formed question, or a question which might change while you fix the problems identified above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b].$ Let $E=\{x:f(x)\ge 0\}$ and $g=\chi_E.$

Is $g$ Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]?$ Yes. Proof: Because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed for any closed set $A.$ Therefore $E =f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ is closed, and hence measurable. Therefore $\chi_E$ is measurable. A bounded measurable function is always Lebesgue integrable on a set of finite measure. Since $[a,b]$ has finite measure, $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b].$

Is $g$ Riemann integrable (RI)? Not always. Let $U$ be an open subset of $[a,b]$ containing the rationals in $[a,b],$ such that $0<m(U)<b-a.$ Let $E=[a,b]\setminus U.$ Then $E$ is closed, nowhere dense, with $m(E)>0.$

Define $f(x)=-d(x,E).$ Then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f<0$ on $U$ and $f=0$ on $E.$ Thus $E=\{x:f(x)\ge 0\},$ which is what we want. Claim: $g=\chi_E$ is discontinuous at each point of $E.$ To prove this, note that if $x\in E,$ there is a sequence of rationals converging to $x.$ Along this sequence we have $g=0$ whereas $g(x)=1.$ This proves the claim and shows $g$ is not RI by Lebesgue's criterion.

At the end you ask if there are natural conditions on the class of continuous functions for which $g$ is integrable.  Since $g$ is always Lebesgue integrable, I'll take this as a question about RI. In fact there are $C^\infty$ functions such that the corresponding functions $g$ are not RI. The proof is a fancier version of what we did above. Let $U,E$ be exactly what we did above. Then there exists $f\in C^\infty[a,b]$ such that $f=0$ on $E$ and $f<0$ on $U.$ Then we get the same result: $g=\chi_E$ fails to be RI by Lebesgue's criterion.

Here's a condition that gives a positive result: If $f$ is real analytic on $[a,b],$ then the corresponding $g$ is RI. That's because the zero set of $f$ is either everything, or just a finite set. It follows that $E$ is a finite disjoint union of closed subintervals of $[a,b],$ from which the RI of $g=\chi_E$ follows easily.